# Logic: What are the faults in my solution?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

1. Show that $(\neg q \wedge (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow \neg p$ is a tautology.

The solution is:
\begin{align}
(\neg q \wedge (p \rightarrow q)) \rightarrow \neg p &\equiv \neg q \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \rightarrow \neg p \\
&\equiv 
((\neg q \wedge \neg p) \vee (\neg q \wedge q)) \rightarrow \neg p \\
&\equiv \neg (((\neg q \wedge \neg p) \vee (\neg q \wedge q))) \vee p \\
&\equiv \neg(\neg q \wedge \neg p) \vee \neg p \equiv q
\end{align}
As a result, it is NOT a tautology. What is the fault in this proof?

2. (edit) I am somewhat confused of syllogism.
   Premise: $p \rightarrow q$, $q \rightarrow \neg p$.
   Then, can we conclude $p \rightarrow \neg p$?

Comment: You jumped the gun at the last step. $\neg(\neg q \land \neg p) \lor \neg p \equiv q \lor p \lor \neg p = q\lor T \equiv T$.

Comment: @jl00 Oh I see. That is a fault. Thanks.

Comment: For your second question, yes, and note that $p\implies\lnot p$ is equivalent to $\lnot p$.

Comment: Use truth Tables to verify your assumptions and Transformations.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question, yes, that is absolutely correct.

...and I suspect that that will prompt another question, so I am going to get in first.  Given $p\to(\neg p)$, what can you deduce about $p$?

Comment: Is it true for the implication $p \rightarrow \neg p$? I am very confused...

Comment: @filterhash $p \rightarrow \neg p$ [is logically equivalent to](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cbright/logic/truthtable.php?formula=%28p%3E%7Ep%29%3D%7Ep&output=html) $\neg p.$